# rails - angularjs sends http.get as html format request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have this piece of angularjs code

```
  $http.get(sprintf("/posts/%s", post.id)).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.post = data;
  })
```

I expected in the backend (rails) to get a json format request

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @post}
end
```

But I got a html format request.

Something I am missing? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
$http.get(sprintf("/posts/%s.json", post.id)).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.post = data;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, IS there a better way other than adding .json  to the url?

Comment: Well, as long as your Rails controller responds to both html and json, your Angular app needs to tell Rails that it wants `json`. You could modify `Accept` header with `$httpProvider` or tell Rails to always serve json for requests with `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, but I believe it is simple and best to just put `.json`.